# TTK, Buttons only have one number on them

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    numpad = NumPad(root)
    root.mainloop()

numbers = [
'7',  '8',  '9',
'4',  '5',  '6',
'1',  '2',  '3']


class NumPad(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.grid()
        self.num()

    def num(self):
        for c in range(1,4):
            for r in range(3):
                for b in numbers:
                    cmd = lambda b=b: print(b)
                    self.b= ttk.Button(self, text=b, command=cmd).grid(row = r, column = c, pady = 5)
                    #print(b)

main()
```

I'm having an issue with this code, as when I try to run it all the buttons only have 3 on them, and the only output is 3. I tried looking at what I did wrong, but still can't find the error. It only picks the last number that is in the "Numbers" function.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `self.b` in the last inner loop. Try this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    numpad = NumPad(root)
    root.mainloop()

numbers = [
'7',  '8',  '9',
'4',  '5',  '6',
'1',  '2',  '3']


class NumPad(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.grid()
        self.num()

    def num(self):
        for c in range(3):
            for r in range(3):
                text = numbers[c*3+r]
                cmd = lambda text=text: print(text)
                self.b= ttk.Button(self, text=text, command=cmd).grid(row = r, column = c, pady = 5)

main()
```

Comment: I see how it goes now. The only difference is that the numbers go vertically first, then horizontally. I can just fix that by changing the order around.

Comment: Correct. I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 3):

For each spot on your grid, you are creating 9 buttons and putting one on top of the other.  Only the last button (the one corresponding to 3) ends up showing up and it shows up every time.  Instead, you need to figure out the index based on `c` and `r` and only create 1 button:

```
def num(self):
    for c in range(1,4):
        for r in range(3):
            b = (c - 1) * 3 + r
            cmd = lambda b=b: print(b)
            self.b= ttk.Button(self, text=b, command=cmd).grid(row = r, column = c, pady = 5)
            #print(b)
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix this by doing this instead
                #print(b)
                c += 1
                if c > 2:
                    c = 0
                    r += 1'

Answer (score 0):

Pair each row-column coordinate with one item from `numbers` using `zip`:

```
def num(self):
    rc_gen = ((r, c) for r in range(3) for c in range(3))
    for (r, c), num in zip(rc_gen, numbers):
        cmd = lambda num=num: print(num)
        self.b = ttk.Button(self, text=num, command=cmd).grid(row=r, column=c, pady=5)
```